# How can i do the unit testing of this c# program?

Tags: c#, nunit

The given program is:

```
public Adoption adoptionProcess(Client theClient, ref int numberToAdopt, 
                ArrayList animalList)
{
    ArrayList adoptedAnimals = new ArrayList();
    int currentAnimal = 0;
    double adoptionFee = 0;
    while (numberToAdopt > 0)
    {
        Animal thisAnimal = (Animal)animalList[currentAnimal];
        if (!thisAnimal.adopted)
        {
            adoptedAnimals.Add(thisAnimal);
            adoptionFee += thisAnimal.getadoptionFee();
            thisAnimal.adopted = true;
            numberToAdopt--;
        }
        currentAnimal++;
    }
    return new Adoption(theClient, adoptionFee, adoptedAnimals);
}
```

Unit testing I have tried is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void adoptionProcessTest()
{
    Client amrit = new Client("Amrit", "Amrit", " 1", "Melbourne", 
                            "9898989898", "aamrit10@gmail.com");
    ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
    myAL.Add("anim1");
    myAL.Add("anim2");
    myAL.Add("anim3");


    AdoptAPet adopt = new AdoptAPet();
    Adoption actual = adopt.adoptionProcess(amrit, ref num, myAL);
    Adoption expected = new Adoption(amrit, 1, );
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

It shows error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'amrit.Animal'.

Comment: On which line??

Comment: This part looks strange to me, **new Adoption(amrit, 1, )**

Comment: On which line is it showing the error for? What does the `Client` constructor look like?

Comment: It looks like you have a missing parameter  on your `Adoption expected` declaration

Comment: Please post the complete error dump/stack, not just the description.

Comment: Error message pretty clear, you are using somewhere variable of wrong type. Sure you will be able find solution by yourself if you investigate exception details carefully. With information you provide is impossible answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code that are leading you astray.

```
public Adoption adoptionProcess(Client theClient, ref int numberToAdopt, 
                ArrayList animalList)
```

This tells the compiler `animalList` is an `ArrayList`, which is an array of any types of data.

```
Animal thisAnimal = (Animal)animalList[currentAnimal];
```

This only accepts elements of `animalList` that are `Animal`s, which contradicts what you told the compiler. Arrays support things like searching, sorting, and indexing, but the only thing you do with it is go through each element in order. `ArrayList` is a very bad choice for your function; it doesn't support what you need (only contains `Animal`) and requires a lot of things you don't need. A better choice for representing `animalList` is `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

Next, you're passing `numberToAdopt` to `adoptionProcess` and using that to count how many animals are in `animalList`. But you already know the number of animals from `animalList.Count()` and you don't test to see if `numberToAdopt > animalList.Count()`. Why do you even store this? The number of adopted animals will be in `adoptedAnimals.Count()`, all you're doing is keeping two separate copies of the same data, copies which can easily go out of sync. If you're trying to restrict the number of animals in `adoptedAnimals` then put the restriction in `AdoptAPet`. If you're trying to restrict the number of animals in `animalList` then prune that list before passing it to `adoptionProcess`; don't pass data you don't need to functions.

Your test method contains code like:

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
myAL.Add("anim1");
...
Adoption actual = adopt.adoptionProcess(amrit, ref num, myAL);
```

This won't even compile, and when you fix the compiler errors you'll get a runtime exception because `myAL` is a list of strings and `adoptionProcess` can only handle lists of `Animal`s. You want to do something like:

```
var testAnimals = new List<Animal> {
    new Animal(you need to put something here),
    new Animal(you need to put something here),
    ...
}
var actual = adopt.AdoptionProcess(amrit, testAnimals);
```

Your `AdoptionProcess` should look more like this:

```
public Adoption AdoptionProcess(Client theClient, IEnumerable<Animal> animalList)
{
    var adoptedAnimals = new List<Animal>();
    decimal adoptionFee = 0;
    foreach (var animal in animalList)
    {
        if (!animal.adopted)
        {
            adoptedAnimals.Add(animal);
            adoptionFee += animal.getadoptionFee();
            animal.adopted = true;
        }
    }

    return new Adoption(theClient, adoptionFee, adoptedAnimals);
}
```

Then fix the mistakes in `adoptionProcessTest` the compiler points out.

Your code

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

will call `expected.Equals(actual)` which, unless you've overwritten `Adoption.Equals()`, will call a reference comparison which is probably not what you want.

Then consider making `AdoptAPet` and `AdoptionProcess` methods of `Client` and avoid passing theClient everywhere.

Comment: _is very poorly-written_ is very broad argument, which provide zero information. Can you explain reasons why your solution is "better"?